# Laravel Maatwebsite\Excel export

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5, export-to-excel, maatwebsite-excel

I have problem on exporting to excel using laravel maatwebsite excel, i can do export but it will export all in series.My problem is, I want to assign the result in every cell. Example:A1 = Agency Name, B1 = Division Name, A3:E3 = Account Title (merge), A5 - E5 = Table header, A6 - E6 = result of foreach data. In short, I want to assign the result in specific cell, to make like a formatted report. I try to search here but i didnt find result that explain or show how to pud the exported result to an specific excel cell

Example:

`A1:E1 = Company Name`
`A2:E2 = Department`
`A3:E3 = Company Address`
`A5 = Unit B5 = Item C5 = Description D5 = Quantity E5 = Date Issued`

```
$ews->setCellValue('a1', 'Company name'); 
$ews->setCellValue('b1', 'Company Division');
$ews->setCellValue('A3:E3', 'Account Title');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all in series"? I don't see any kind of series in that given code

Comment: I mean "all in series" is all records in my database was downloaded and start in cell A1 and so on...i want to download only one record and formatted as our report template like whast i stated above. I want the result as the code given, like for example. from my database column "Company Name" should put in cell A1 and Department should put in B1, Account title should in A3, and other data should put on the specific cells in excel

Comment: i want to specify the result like this: $sheet->cell('A1', function($cell) 
{

  $cells->setFontWeight('bold');

});

Comment: Please add all clarification to the question by editing it. This should also cover what **exactly** the problem is

Comment: Resolve, I use PHPOffice/spreadsheet to export my desired output view in excel

Answer (score 0):

**- You can limit the records by the query by selecting only records which you need for example:**

```
$Report = Invoice::select('id', 'pickup', 'dropoff', 'pickup_date', 'created_at', 'updated_at')->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
```

**- for specifying the range of cells you can do this by registering event in the export file in my example I selected the range $cellRange = 'A1:AA1';:**

```
public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
            $cellRange = 'A1:AA1';
            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize(14);
        },
    ];
}
```

I hope this can help you